# How to force react router to reopen a page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a `<Link` on my sidebar
I want to refresh an open page.
But if the page is already open it doesn't reload the page.
A side effect is that when the sidebar is opened (left drawer) it doesn't hide, as if I didn't click on the item.

Comment: On componentDidMount of the page just reset the Sidebar or Reset the side bar on componentWillUnmount of previously loaded component

Comment: It will not reload the page if the props have not changed so you can try componentDidUpdate() and see if that works

Comment: 1. It does not get to any of the functions (componentDidMount, componentWillMount, render). 
2. What do you mean reset the sidebar? how?